# How to generate bigger value for Y=X/N when X becomes smaller?

Tags: calculus, nonlinear-system

I am not specialist in Math, I just want to know if there is any operation(or formulation) that can be used to return bigger value for ***Y*** when ***X*** becomes smaller?
I have tried to use Square root
For example:

Square root and exponential operations returns smaller value for Y when X value become smaller and this is not what I want.

```
   N = 200
   Y = X/N
```

**Using Square root**

```
Y = sqrt(10/200) = 0.2236
Y = sqrt(5/200) = 0.15811
```

**Same with exponential operation**

```
Y = exp(10/200) = 1.0513    
Y = exp(5/200) = 1.0253
```

**I have this formulation:**

```
Y = X/N   ;   where ***N*** is constant
Z = 2-2*(Y)^5
```

Here the value of X changes over time. When X becomes smaller, the value of **Y** should became bigger. Then, **Z** becomes smaller. The value of **Z** ***must be positive*** in interval [0,2].

***Y*** value ***must be positive***.

**Which operation can be used to do this?**

Comment: Have you tried something in the form $y = c/x$? If $f(x)$ is a constantly increasing function in some positive interval, $y  = c/f(x)$ could prove to work nicely too, depending on what you are looking for.

Comment: @Hyperion I have edited the question. would you please check it.

Comment: Your last step is incorrect. $y = x (\frac{1}{n})$ suggests that as $x$ gets smaller, $y$ also gets smaller. You need to change your model to get you desired result. I recommend watching the following video on direct variation vs. inverse variation.

https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra2/rational-expressions-equations-and-functions/direct-and-inverse-variation/v/direct-and-inverse-variation

Comment: @Hyperion  Yes, in this formulation, Y=X(1/N) , when X gets smaller Y also gets smaller. That is why I need to add something with X to make Y bigger when X gets smaller. Then, final result Z gets smaller